# Xcode 10.0 error: Couldn't IRGen expression, no additional error

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

When I'm running the app and want to debug something the response is:

- expression produced error: error: Couldn't IRGen expression, no additional error

How can I make it evaluate my expression instead?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/52716637/718925