# Xcode 10, LLDB: Couldn't IRGen expression

Tags: lldb, xcode10, swift4.2

Using Xcode 10, when I stop my app using a breakpoint and try to print the content of an object in the Console, I obtain:

> "Couldn't IRGen expression, no additional error"

However, I can see the value of the object in the Variables View panel.

[image]

How can I make it evaluate my expression instead?

Comment: I have the same issue with Xcode 10.1. May be it is related to break point in background thread?

Comment: @BillChan, I don't think so, In my sample I'm in the main thread.

Comment: Do you use Carthage? I find a article said if the framework is a binary not locally built.

Comment: Try `fr v variableName`

Comment: @Kamil.S this works! I'll look for the differences. Thanks

Comment: @BillChan, I've just rebuilt every frameworks imported with Carthage and now even `po variable` works, thanks. (can you please post the link to the article you mentioned?)

Comment: https://imtx.me/archives/2719.html

Comment: This worked like a charm for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62417641/6342609

Answer (score 13):

In `lldb` as a **workaround**  you can use:

```
fr v productVersion
fr v productBuild
```

since Xcode 10.2

```
v productVersion
v productBuild
```

which prints local variable type and address from current call stack frame.

Apple documentation for these kind of lldb capabilities: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/lldb-guide/chapters/C5-Examining-The-Call-Stack.html

UPDATE:
Another trick that seems to help is to set
[image]

Comment: Can you provide more information where you have found it and what it does?

Comment: @milo Added, hope that helps.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks.
I solved with rebuild carthage framework like imtx.me/archives/2719.html

`carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries`

Comment: Please include the command for carthage that solved the problem in your answer

Comment: There's no word about Carthage in question

Answer (score 1):

I had defined as build system: "Legacy Build System", I changed it to "New Build System", then I build the project, and then I put it back as "Legacy Build System" and it worked again.

For to change the build mode: File->Workspace settings...->Build System

Comment: not working for my case. I have added two new targets also.

Answer (score 0):

For my colleague, `carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries` was working but it was not for me. When I removed the `Carthage` folder and reran the command, the `po` command started working . I'm not sure if it's related but I'm on macOS Catalina 10.15.3 and he is on Mojave. We both have Carthage version 0.34.0.

Answer (score 0):

> My env: Xcode 11.6 and Xcode 12 Beta 6, carthage 0.34.0

In my case, my company wants me to make build of our app out of Xcode 12 beta and see what's broken. I did it and encounter [another bug](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/3019) that crippled the carthage. I fixed it by following [this answer](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/3019#issuecomment-665136323) in the [same thread](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/3019).

Then I switched back to Xcode 11.6, the error started to appear

> error: Couldn't IRGen expression, no additional error

The variable inspector works normally but debug console is useless without print or po. It took me some time to search in SO before I realized this might be related to carthage. Then I updated all my dependencies using the following command

```
carthage bootstrap --platform iOS --no-use-binaries --cache-builds
```

Then the debug resume normal and I can use print/po again